# Find NON-overlapping (date/time) rows within one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores 2 calendars events that each row is a meeting with event_id (int), calendar_id (int - 1/2), start (datetime) and end (datetime).

Desired output: 
New table with event_id from calendar_id(1), start and end that has no event overlapping with events from calendar_id(2).

For example, for the following input:
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mGOS.png)

```
eventid | calendaid | start        | end
    101 |         1 | 1/1/10 20:00 | 1/1/10 22:00 
    102 |         2 | 1/1/10 20:00 | 1/1/10 21:00 
    103 |         1 | 1/1/10 22:00 | 1/2/10 02:00 
    104 |         2 | 1/1/10 22:00 | 1/2/10 02:00 
    105 |         1 | 1/2/10 01:00 | 1/2/10 05:00
    106 |         2 | 1/2/10 01:00 | 1/2/10 02:00 
    107 |         1 | 1/2/10 05:00 | 1/2/10 06:00 
    108 |         2 | 1/2/10 05:00 | 1/2/10 08:00 
    109 |         1 | 1/2/10 06:00 | 1/2/10 08:00
    110 |         2 | 1/2/10 03:00 | 1/2/10 04:00
```

Output should be the following:

```
eventid | start        | end 
    101 | 1/1/10 21:00 | 1/1/10 22:00
    105 | 1/2/10 02:00 | 1/2/10 03:00 
    105 | 1/2/10 04:00 | 1/2/10 05:00
```

Is there any way to perform such a query in MySQL?

Comment: Actually, I'm not looking for the most efficient way to solve this problem, I'm just looking for a solution. 
I've changed the question, sorry for the deception !

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: Is that the second of January or the first of February?

Comment: Second of January

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from calendars c
where c.calendarid = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from calendars c2
                  where c2.calendarid = 2 and
                        c2.start < c.end and
                        c2.end > c.start
                 );
```

The overlap logic assumes that events that overlap only on the start/end datetimes are not overlapping.

There is no particularly efficient way to implement this logic.  An index on `(calendarid, start, end)` might help.